# Request Problem in Spring Boot through Postman and Swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, swagger

I have a problem about sending the same request through Postman and Swagger in Spring Boot.

When I send a request through Postman, it is successfully sent without any issue.
When I send a request through Swagger, I get an error with status 500. Then I open the console and this error message is shown like this.

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.refreshtokenjwt.app.modal.Role
```

Here is my User Entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User extends IdBasedEntity implements Serializable {

    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Here is my Role Entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Roles")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role extends IdBasedEntity implements Serializable {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 20)
    private ERole name;

    public Role(ERole name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ERole getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Here is my requests shown below. I don't get any issue in first request. After I send second request , I get an error.

```
{
    "username" : "User1",
    "password" : "user1",
    "email" : "user1_role_user@refreshtoken.com",
    "roles" : [
        "ROLE_USER"
    ]
}

{
    "username" : "User2",
    "password" : "user2",
    "email" : "user2_role_user@refreshtoken.com",
    "roles" : [
        "ROLE_USER"
    ]
}
```

Here is my method defined in RestController.

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody SignupRequest signUpRequest) {

        LOGGER.info("AuthController | registerUser is started");

        String username = signUpRequest.getUsername();
        String email = signUpRequest.getEmail();
        String password = signUpRequest.getPassword();
        Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRoles();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if(userService.existsByUsername(username)){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
        }

        if(userService.existsByEmail(email)){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new MessageResponse("Error: Email is already taken!"));
        }

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(password));


        if (strRoles != null) {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                LOGGER.info("AuthController | registerUser | role : " + role);
                switch (role) {
                    case "ROLE_ADMIN":

                        Role adminRole = null;

                        if(roleService.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN).isEmpty()){
                            adminRole = new Role(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN);
                        }else{
                            adminRole = roleService.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                                        .orElseThrow(() -> new RoleException("Error: Admin Role is not found."));
                        }

                        roles.add(adminRole);
                        break;

                    case "ROLE_MODERATOR":

                        Role moderatorRole = null;

                        if(roleService.findByName(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR).isEmpty()){
                            moderatorRole = new Role(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR);
                        }else{
                            moderatorRole = roleService.findByName(ERole.ROLE_MODERATOR)
                                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RoleException("Error: Moderator Role is not found."));
                        }

                        roles.add(moderatorRole);

                        break;

                    default:

                        Role userRole = null;

                        if(roleService.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER).isEmpty()){
                            userRole = new Role(ERole.ROLE_USER);
                        }else{
                            userRole = roleService.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RoleException("Error: User Role is not found."));
                        }

                        roles.add(userRole);

                }

            });
        }else{

            Role userRole = new Role();
            userRole.setName(ERole.ROLE_USER);

            roles.add(userRole);
        }

        user.setRoles(roles);
        userService.saveUser(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
    }
```

Here is my SignUpRequest class shown below.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SignupRequest {

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 20)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 6, max = 40)
    private String password;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Email
    private String email;

    private Set<String> roles;

}
```

Comment: Can you please also add the request you're sending?

Comment: I dont think the reason for the exception is a different use of a http client. The issue lies in   handling the Request-Object and how the deserialized objects are mapped to entities. you need to show the code of restcontroller and underlying service please

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann I updated my post. Here is my github repository. https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootRefreshTokenJWT

Comment: Any reason why you store the role as a separate entity instead of just using a string or number for the name or ordinal of that ERole enum?
I think that you can have only three elements in the role table and would have to link the right one to your user entity instead of just hoping that JPA will search and link it for you.

(and btw: I had a "hard time" for a short moment browsing your repo - you should rename that "modal" package to "model")

Comment: @cyberbrain I changed Cascade type and fetch type in ManytoMany annotation but I got the same issue. How can I fix it?

Comment: get rid of that `Role` class at all, just use the `ERole` as type and annotate the field with `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`. I'm not 100% sure that this works with a `Set<ERole>` also, so I just write this as comment, not as answer ;)

Comment: @cyberbrain I didn't work.

Comment: just a thought: do you reset (recreate the tables) each time you change the entities/models?

Comment: @cyberbrain No.

Comment: ok, let it say differently: whenever you change the structure of your model (and changing annotations like ManyToMany also does this!) you have to recreate your database tables for that changed model. Otherwise you will be stuck with the old model that doesn't fit then to the new code.  
For development it could help if you use an in-memory database like h2, that is recreated on each start of the software.

Comment: @cyberbrain Have you ever tested my signup method? If not, you first test it. I also get this error . javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2. There is a problem in roles part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242823/discussion-between-cyberbrain-and-tony-brand).